# Find a point on finite line which has a given radius

Tags: analysis, vectors, vector-analysis

I have given a line L defined by two points $(x_1,y_1)$ $(x_2,y_2)$. I want to find a point on the line which has a given radius $r$.

[image]

I already have a solution with the approach to calculate the intersection point between a finite line and a circle. Is there a solution which is more simple?

Comment: In effect, every approach is going to calculate the intersection point between a finite line segment and a circle, since that's exactly the problem you have here. We don't know how you did it, so it's only a guess whether another approach might be simpler. If you're really interested in answers, you might try showing the steps of your approach.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted to get some inspiration what is also possible. My solution I found on Wolfram MathWorld. You will also find it if you google "infinite line circle intersection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way which you might find easier is to write the coordinates of the point of interest in the form $$(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$

This point lies on the line $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

In which case, $\theta $ satisfies $$r\sin\theta-mr\cos\theta=y_1-mx_1$$

This can be written, using a compound angle transformation, as $$\sin(\theta-\arctan m)=\frac{y_1-mx_1}{r\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

You can then find the value of $\theta$.

You might find this numerically simpler than the method you described.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. In my case my approach is actually still more elegant. But also I got here a solution so thank you very much for making me smarter.

Comment: You are welcome